# "A derived-class constructor cannot catch exceptions thrown by its base-class constructor." But able to catch it

Tags: java, exception

The below statement is from thinking in java, "A derived-class constructor cannot catch exceptions thrown by its base-class constructor." But I am able to catch it. Can Anyone explain where I went wrong?

```
class Base {
    Base() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {

    Derived() throws CloneNotSupportedException, RuntimeException {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Derived d = new Derived();
        }
        catch(CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(RuntimeException re){}
    }
}
```

output:

```
    java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException
    at Base.<init>(Coffee.java:4)
    at Derived.<init>(Coffee.java:9)
    at Derived.main(Coffee.java:14)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not catching anything in the derived class's constructor. You catch the exceptions in the main method. Therefore you are not contradicting the quote you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how your derived-class constructor would have to look in order to catch an exception from the base-class constructor:

```
Derived() {
   try { 
     super(); 
   } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
     System.out.println("We have indeed caught an exception from the "+
          "base-class constructor! The book was wrong!");
   }
}
```

Try it and see what comes out.

Comment: the book is correct. when I modified my derived class as u gave. it is giving me complie time error that "call to super must be first statement in constructor" so I guess we cant catch that exception

Comment: Exactly the point of my answer. The best way to learn is by finding out yourself.